# odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: project_manage.view_project_turn_over_action" in Odoo12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

there are two xml files,the first one has a button,and another is the form view xml.
It should jump to the form view xml,when I click the button.
But I had a mistake：odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: project_manage.view_test_project_turn_over_action"
(project_manage is the module name and view_test_project_turn_over_action is the action id,both button xml and form view xml are in the module 'project_manage'.)

the button xml:

```
<button name="%(view_test_project_turn_over_action)d" string="Turn over" type="action"/>
```

the form view xml:

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="view_test_project_turn_over_action">
    <field name="name">Turn Over Form</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">test.project.turn.over</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_test_project_turn_over_form"/>
    <field name="target">new</field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because sequence of xml files listed in manifest file.

To avoid sequence problem, you can always use external id with module name.

Like

```
module_name.xml_id
```

In your case, it would be

```
%(project_manage.view_test_project_turn_over_action)d
```

Or you can change sequence of xml file listing in manifest file.